# Habilitar "imagem destacada" em páginas específicas do WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Utilizei o seguinte comando para habilitar as "imagens destacadas" nos posts de meu site em WordPress:

```
// HABILITANDO IMAGENS DESTACADAS EM POSTS
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post'));
```

Como habilitar esta função em algumas páginas específicas do site? Não quero habilitar em todas as páginas. Apenas, por exemplo, na página "Sobre" e na página "Contato".

Comment: Para habilitar para as páginas basta acrescentar o tipo _page_ no _array_: `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post','page'));`.

Para limitar a exibição em páginas seria necessário criar uma função para identificar no `header.php` qual a página que está sendo acessada, e mostrar ou não a imagem destacada.

Answer (score 0):

Só é possível fazer esse refinamento com CSS ou JavaScript.

A ação é aplicada só nas páginas `wp-admin/post.php` e `wp-admin/post-new.php`.
A global `$current_screen` tem a informação do Post Type que está sendo mostrado.
E a global `$post` tem as informações sobre o post atual onde verificamos o permalink, p.ex.: `http://site.com/contato`.

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'metabox_sopt_279492' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'metabox_sopt_279492' );

function metabox_sopt_279492() {
    global $current_screen, $post;
    if ( 'page' != $current_screen->id ) 
        return; 

    $checkpages = array( 'sobre', 'contato' );
    if( in_array( $post->post_name, $checkpages ) )
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {   
            $('#postimagediv').remove(); 
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Resposta excluída ok. obg: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288920/8063

Comment: Imagino que falta pouco pro seu [Martelinho de Ouro](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/1287812) em [tag:javascript], boa sorte!