# trocar pseudo :after com jquery

Tags: javascript

Como posso trocar o estilo da uma classe :after utilizando jquery?

tentei assim mas não deu certo:

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.box:after').css({
    borderColor:' #c12 transparent transparent transparent'
});
```

Comment: Neo, edite sua pergunta e inclua o html.

Answer (score 2):

*pseudo-elementos* (`::after`, `::before` etc.) não estão na árvore do DOM, portanto não estão acessíveis via JavaScript.

Esses elementos só são visíveis na tela, mas não estão na árvore de elementos do DOM, conforme dito. Caso queira alterá-los, terá que adicionar uma classe específica.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("#b1").click(function(){
   $(".box").addClass("novaclasse");
});

$("#b2").click(function(){
   $(".box").removeClass("novaclasse");
});
```

```css
.box:after{
   content: 'after';
   border: 10px solid #000;
   border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* classe que irá alterar o :after */
.box.novaclasse:after{
   border-color: #c12 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
   principal
</div>
<br>
<input id="b1" type="button" value="Clique para alterar">
<br>
<em>Irá adicionar a classe .novaclasse</em>
<br><br>
<input id="b2" type="button" value="Clique para voltar original">
<br>
<em>Irá remover a classe .novaclasse</em>
```

Comment: deu certo, obrigado! https://jsfiddle.net/kdqbz7rt/2/

Comment: Não entendi, votou pra fechar como duplicata da sua própria resposta e respondeu de novo aqui?

Comment: Perguntas duplicadas tudo bem, respostas auto-duplicadas parece estranho...

Comment: Se você tivesse medalha de ouro na tag JavaScript, seu voto ia fechar a pergunta imediatamente. E se respondesse e depois fechasse imediatamente, ia ser uso indevido do sistema.

Comment: Bueno, a conversa entrou em loop. See ya!

Comment: Como pequeno aparte, também não concordo com dar uma resposta se sabe que é duplicada e inclusivamente já votou para fechar a pergunta como tal. O facto de a questão estar aberta é uma questão de tempo. O site tem o sistema de duplicadas precisamente para evitar ter a mesma resposta espalhada em milhares de perguntas. No final acaba por não acrescer conteúdo e apenas o replicar vezes sem fim sem nenhum beneficio.

Comment: desculpa, não compreendi a questão da duplicata.. mas vou desmarcar como o dvd pediu...

Comment: A questão que não consigo visualizar só falando pra criar uma classe...queria um exemplo de como eu consigo entrar no before e mudar o background.

Comment: @Thiagolourenço Não tem como entrar no before através do JavaScript.

Comment: @sam, esse foi o meu questionamento...até agora não achei nada. Achei apenas pra mudar o "content", ou então alguma forma alternativa.